# Cannot locate node of type [septentrio_gnss_driver_node]

Tags: package, driver, ros, launch, ros2

when I launch `roslaunch septentrio_gnss_driver rover.launch param_file_name:=rover` 
having following launch file for github [repo](https://github.com/septentrio-gnss/septentrio_gnss_driver/tree/master)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="node_name" default="septentrio_gnss" />
  <arg name="param_file_name" />
  <arg name="output" default="screen" />
  <arg name="respawn" default="false" />
  <arg name="clear_params" default="true" />

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_imu"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link imu" />

    <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_gnss"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 imu gnss" />

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_vsm"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 imu vsm" />

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_aux1"
        args="0 0 0 0 0 0 imu aux1" />

  <node pkg="septentrio_gnss_driver" type="septentrio_gnss_driver_node" name="$(arg node_name)"
        output="$(arg output)" 
        clear_params="$(arg clear_params)"
        respawn="$(arg respawn)">
    <rosparam command="load" 
              file="$(find septentrio_gnss_driver)/config/$(arg param_file_name).yaml" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

I get following error

`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [septentrio_gnss_driver/septentrio_gnss_driver_node]: Cannot locate node of type [septentrio_gnss_driver_node] in package [septentrio_gnss_driver]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)`
I already install septentrio_gnss_driver for ros noetic by `sudo apt install ros-noetic-septentrio-gnss-driver`

Comment: Did you source your local working directory or the setup file on `/opt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For package installation verification you need to manually run the node you are writting in launch file to execute . Also try pressing double **TAB** key before writing node name to check if package was found.

> ros2 run <package_name> <node_name>

- If node is not found check this repository where all **sudo** installed package go into

> /opt/ros/humble/lib/

- List all packages and find yours .
- I have produced a video about it as well -> [link](https://youtu.be/Qw9RR1jShYQ)

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.